# How to correctly do maths with higher numbers in PHP

Tags: php, math

I am trying to display the total amount which is product price times quantity.

This works perfectly for numbers under 1000, but above that a dot is added and my script breaks. How can I fix that?

I have these numbers:

```
150,00
1.200,00
```

They are looped with variable `$price`.

I then replace all commas for dots like this:

```
$subtotalreken = str_replace(',','.',$price);
```

`$subtotalreken then contains`:

```
150.00
1.200.00
```

I then multiply this with the quantity amount like this:

```
$totalfinal = $subtotalreken * $cart['quantity'];
```

The quantity is 2 for both products, and if I echo `$totalfinal`, this is my result:

```
300
2.4
```

Why is it 2.4? And not 2.400?

I need the european/dutch format, so dots for every three numbers and cents after the comma. How can I do that?

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? Why does your code add dots allover the process? Why not format numbers as they need to be outputted only?

Comment: FYI http://php.net/number_format

Comment: Use `$subtotalreken = number_format($price,2,'.','');`

Comment: PHP does not add thousands separators automatically. More, the standard decimal separator in php is a dot, not a comma. You must be doing something to add them, like formatting numbers as strings according to locale settings with sprintf. Please explain where your numbers 1.200,00 come from.

Comment: **^ that** ... this question has a hint of [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) about it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before calculations remove any formatting from your number (just make sure you always have 2 decimal places number):

```
$number = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $input);
```

Then do your calculations (number is in cents) and show to user formatted number:

```
echo number_format($number * $qunatity / 100, '.', ',', 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the "number" uses comma as decimal and dots as thousands separator: remove all dots and replace the comma with dot so that `1.234,56` becomes `1234.56`:

```
$value = (float) strtr("1.234,56", ["." => "", "," => "."]); // 1234.56
```

You can format the value again using number_format:

```
echo number_format($value, 2, ",", "."); // 1.234,56
```